# select datetime closest to a specified value for every day in a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, select

I have 2 simple tables defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[shop](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [name] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    [brand] [ntext] NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[shop_history](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [shopid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,     (references shop.id)
    [totalstockval] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL
)
```

With data:

```
**dbo.shop**
id    | name    | brand
--------------------------
    1 |  Bow Rd | Tesco
    2 | Wren Rd | Tesco
    3 | Skye Rd | Safeway

**dbo.shop_history**
id    | shopid  | totalstockval  | date
----------------------------------------------
  997 |       1 |       19923031 | 2017-02-01 08:00
  998 |       1 |       19323322 | 2017-02-01 08:30
  999 |       1 |       19283873 | 2017-02-01 09:45
 1000 |       2 |       14949321 | 2017-02-01 07:00
 1001 |       2 |       12312312 | 2017-02-01 09:30
 1002 |       3 |       12232344 | 2017-01-31 23:45
 1003 |       3 |       12999222 | 2017-02-01 09:45
```

I have a full years worth of similar data. I want to query the data to find the latest stock value each day BEFORE 09:00, even if that occurred the previous day.

The resultset I'm trying to achieve would look like:

```
shop.id |    name |   brand | totalstockval |              date
---------------------------------------------------------------
      1 |  Bow Rd |   Tesco |      19323322 |  2017-02-01 08:30
      2 | Wren Rd |   Tesco |      14949321 |  2017-02-01 07:00
      3 | Skye Rd | Safeway |      12232344 |  2017-01-31 23:45
```

repeated for each day of the year. If there's no value row on a particular day, use the latest available value.

I have a feeling I would need a tally table containing every date (or datetime) that I want a price for, but I'm not sure of the query. How can I achieve a resultset similar to the above example?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I've tagged SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

could be you need  a join with a subselect for max date < 9

```
  select t.shopid, b.name, b.brand, t.max_date, a.totalstockvale 
  from  shop_history a 
  inner join (
    select  shopid,  max(date)  max_date
    from shop_history a 
    where time(date) < '09:00'
    group by a.shopid ) t on a.shopid = t.shopid and a.date = t.date
  inner join shop on a.shopid = b.shopid
```

Comment: This works for single day. but I have data for an entire year, so need the daily stockvalue at 9am.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question.  You want the latest `shop_history` record for each shop where the day ends at 9:00 a.m.  One method is to subtract 9 hours and do the calculation based on the resulting date:

```
select sh.*
from (select sh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by shopid,
                                             cast(dateadd(hour, -9, date) as date)
                                order by date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from shop_history sh
     ) sh
where seqnum = 1
```